# How can I show total recurring revenue per year, but only if there is no cancellation date filled?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to build a report based on an excel sheet that has (amongst others) the following columns:

- recurring revenue: this columns show a certain amount (FI € 500,-) per customer, which is billed every year.
- cancellation date: this column shows a date if the customer has cancelled the subscription. FI: if the date 01-06-2020 is filled,
  the recurring revenue should be counted in the total of 2020, but not anymore in 2021.

Does anyone have a formula for how I can show this in a visual? I tried making a new calculated column with the following formula, but this only shows the recurring revenue for the lines in the table that have a cancellation date filled:

Recurring revenue=

var currentdate = SELECTEDVALUE('Date S&A'[Date])
return
CALCULATE(SUM('Licentie & SA'[recurring revenue),'Licentie & SA'[cancellation date] > currentdate )

Some sample data and expected output:

Ok, so some sample data would be (sorry not sure how to format it correctly here):

| Customer | Date start | Cancellation date | Recurring revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-10-2012 | 1-6-2015 | € 816,00 |
| 2 | 1-11-2014 | 1-11-2018 | € 2.645,00 |
| 3 | 1-11-2014 |  | € 1.690,50 |

The expected output would be:

| Year | Total recurring revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2012 | € 816,00 |
| 2013 | € 816,00 |
| 2014 | € 5.151,50 (816,00 + 2.645,00 + 1.690,50) |
| 2015 | € 5.151,50 |
| 2016 | € 4.335,50 (5.151,50 - 816, cause customer 1 cancelled in 2015) |
| 2017 | € 4.335,50 |
| 2018 | € 4.335,50 |
| 2019 | € 1.690,50 (4.335,50 - 2.645,00) |

Comment: It is always easier if you supply some sample data and expected output.

Comment: I'm trying to add some sample data and expected output to the post but Im having some trouble with formatting the table..

Comment: ok should be good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is creating a calendar table based on the data you have supplied.

### Calendar Table

I've ended the calendar in 2019 to simulate the output you have provided.

```
Calendar =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR ( MIN ( 'Table'[Date start] ), DATE ( 2019, 12, 31 ) ),
    "Year", YEAR ( [Date] )
)
```

### Total Recurring Revenue

From there, you can calculate the total for each year with the following calculation.
The main idea here is using `SUMX` to iterate each row of `Table` to calculate the sums. The logic to filter each row is inside `CALCULATE`. It's important to highlight this will only work for years.

```
Total Recurring Revenue = 
VAR _CurrentYear =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Year] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        'Table',
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Table'[Recurring revenue] ),
            _CurrentYear >= YEAR ( 'Table'[Date start] )
                && (
                    _CurrentYear <= YEAR ( 'Table'[Cancellation date] )
                        || ISBLANK ( 'Table'[Cancellation date] )
                )
        )
    )
```

### Ouput

To display the same output, you need to use Year from Calendar and the measure above.

[image]

Comment: Hey Angelo, 

I just tried it and it seems to be working. I already had my own date table so I used that for the year.

Thanks alot for the help !! :)

Comment: Upon further inspection I see its not calculating the totals completely right.
If I look at the year 2014 for instance, it only counts the lines in the table which have a date start in 2014, not the lines that have a start date before that and no end date.

Comment: Can you expand your sample and output data to include that scenario as well?

Comment: I managed to fix it. Problem was that I had set a relationship between date start and date in my calendar table, so the filtering was messed up. Thanks again for the help!